# How do I copy to clipboard text I cut with Ctrl+U?

Tags: bash, readline, interactive

In an interactive shell session, how do I copy to clipboard text that was cut with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>? Without using the mouse, obviously. Thus making it available for other GUI applications, instead of pastable only with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> only in the terminal where the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> was issued.

Update: added `bash` tag to cover answers involving bash-only solutions.

Comment: You get your binding to run `xclip` or similar.

Comment: `^Y` does not remove text; it yanks what was last killed and "pastes" it.  Did you mean `^W`, `^U`, `^K`, `M-D`, and the like?

Comment: Thanks, DopeGhoti. That was a strange mistake. I updated my post.

Comment: I don't think readline has that capacity. Bash does. Do you want this in bash or in some other program?

Comment: @Gilles Bash is absolutely fine.

Comment: @Gilles Any idea why `if [[ -n $DISPLAY ]]; then copy_line_to_x_clipboard() { printf %s "$READLINE_LINE" | xsel -ib; }; bind -x '"\C-u": copy_line_to_x_clipboard'; fi` doesn't work?

Comment: Turns out that stty settings have precedence over bindings, so you need to do `stty kill ''` before `bind -x "\C-u": …`. This could warrant a question of its own if it isn't a duplicate.

Comment: @Gilles Did you see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/423375/how-do-i-share-the-mouse-cut-paste-buffer-not-the-clipboard-between-bash-and-x ?