# How do I share the mouse paste buffer (not the clipboard) between bash and X11 *without* using set-mark?

Tags: bash, keyboard-shortcuts

There is a related answer (link below), but that requires set-mark. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> works differently. `\Cu` or `\C-u` can't just be substituted for the `\eW` (code below).

Here's what [Share the clipboard between bash and X11](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18701/share-the-clipboard-between-bash-and-x11) suggests.

```
if [[ -n $DISPLAY ]]; then
  copy_line_to_x_clipboard () {
    printf %s "$READLINE_LINE" | xsel -ib
  }
  bind -x '"\eW": copy_line_to_x_clipboard'
fi
```

So the question is: how do I make <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> in bash add text that it cuts to Xorg's mouse (middle-click) paste buffer?

Comment: I tried the `stty kill ''` before `bind -x "\C-u"` suggested by @Gilles but the effect is that, on `Ctrl+U`, I get the `^U` itself displayed. No deletion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function does copy the line to the clipboard.

To use the mouse paste buffer rather than the Ctrl+C/Ctrl+V clipboard, run `xsel` without the `-b` option.

To cut rather than copy, delete the text afterwards: set `READLINE_LINE` to an empty string.

Bash gives terminal settings set by `stty` precedence over its own key bindings. I guess the intent is primarily to obey the terminal's settings for [whether BackSpace sends `^H` or `^?`](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Keyboard-and-Console-HOWTO-5.html), but more generally it means that bash's keybindings for all the characters listed by `stty -a` (i.e. `^C`, `^D`, `^H`, `^Q`, `^S`, `^W`, `^Z`, `^\` and `^?`) don't get used by default. You need to unset the stty setting for the control character you want to rebind.

This works for me with the following code in `~/.bashrc` with bash 4.3 on Ubuntu 16.04.

```
if [[ -n $DISPLAY ]]; then
  stty kill ''
  copy_line_to_x_clipboard() {
    printf %s "$READLINE_LINE" | xsel -i;
    READLINE_LINE= READLINE_POINT=0
  };
  bind -x '"\C-u": copy_line_to_x_clipboard';
fi
```

It doesn't work if I just paste this at the command line: I get the effect you mention in a comment, namely, pressing `^U` inserts a literal `^U`. It works if I run `stty kill ''`, then `bind -x …` in a subsequent command.